# How to order by aggregated columns in JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

By executing this JPQL:

```
select o.key, count(o.id), sum(o.errors) from MyEntity o
group by o.key
```

Hibernate commits the following SQL:

```
select
    myentityn0_.key as col_0_0_,
    count(myentityn0_.id) as col_1_0_,
    sum(myentityn0_.errors) as col_2_0_
from
    MYENTITY myentityn0_ 
group by
    myentityn0_.key
```

But how can I use "order by" in this scenario without using the Hibernate-created column names? If I use `as` in JPQL, the SQL doesn't change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name the calculation in the `order by`:

```
select
    o.key,
    count(o.id),
    sum(o.errors)
from MyEntity o
group by o.key
order by sum(o.errors)
```